# How can I patch a hole in this brick wall?

Tags: repair, walls, brick, hole, patch

I just pulled out the washing machine the old owners "kindly" left us to find a hole where the wall meets the floor.

It's approximately 80mm x 50mm and goes down approx 100mm - below ground level - where it seems to open up again. There is a drain near it (on the right of the photo) so I assume this void is due to that. I can feel a breeze when I put my hand near it. Before I put in the new washing machine, I'd like to patch the wall to improve insulation and prevent mice getting in. What's the best way to do this? The wall is brick.

[image: The hole]

---

Edit: Thanks, Bib! Photo of the patch added:

[image: Fixed hole]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can patch it with [hydraulic cement](http://www.homedepot.com/p/DRYLOK-Fast-Plug-10-lb-Hydraulic-Cement-00924/100171483#.Unz4wPmKK8A) similar to this type

[image: hyrdaulic cement]

You need to carefully remove all loose material and clean the area. The cement is fast setting and expands slightly as it sets, making a tight seal. Only mix as much as you can use in a few minutes.

Comment: Thanks! Added a photo of my amateurish fix. Now what do I do with all this leftover wet cement? :-)